# Joining tables creates duplication when there is no relationship, any way to reduce the number of rows?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to join two tables that do not have a common element in the tables but the real life relationship is important. I am able to get data from both tables but it produces row duplication.   Output as follows:

```
Job    Release Date   Release Qty  Ship Date    Qty Shipped  
17760  2/15/13        320          2/14/13      320
17760  3/18/13        250          2/14/13      320
17760  4/11/13        180          2/14/13      320
17760  2/15/13        320          3/13/13      250
17760  3/18/13        250          3/13/13      250
17760  4/11/13        180          3/13/13      250
17760  2/15/13        320          4/08/13      180
17760  3/18/13        250          4/08/13      180
17760  4/11/13        180          4/08/13      180
```

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT PD.oqjob AS Job
 , [OR].ordate AS [Release Date]
 , [OR].orrqty AS [Release Qty]
 , PH.opsdte AS [Ship Date]
 , PD.oqaqty AS [Ship Qty]
FROM
  dbo.opakh PH
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.opakd PD
    ON PH.oppack = PD.oqpack
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.orels [OR]
    ON PD.oqord = [OR].orord AND PD.oqolin = [OR].orline
WHERE
  PD.oqjob = '17760'
```

I would like my output to look like the following with both the **Release Date** and **Packer Date** ordered from earlier to later.

```
Job      Release Date   Release Qty  Ship Date      Qty Shipped
17760    2/15/13 0:00   320.00       2/14/13 0:00   320.00
17760    3/18/13 0:00   250.00       3/13/13 0:00   250.00
17760    4/11/13 0:00   180.00       4/08/13 0:00   180.00
```

Also it is important to note that number of rows returned from the `OR` table may differ from the rows returned by the `PH` table.  Either table could have more rows returned.

Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT: I have redone my SQL statement so Nothing extra is shown nor are there any extra tables or data at the moment**

The `OR` Table contains Three Release dates each with their own quantity

2/15/13    320
3/18/13    250
4/11/13    180

There were three different Packers (Shipping Dates) there is a Packer Header and Packer Detail table `PH` and `PD` respectively.  I need the date from the 'PH' table and the quantity from the `PD` table.  After joining those two tables it looks like this:

2/14/13    320
3/13/13    250
4/08/13    180

I am then trying to join the `PH` & `PD` results with the `OR` results.

Comment: There are multiple different `Ship Date` and `Qty Shipped` for each different release date, how do you know which ones you'd want in your result? (100.00 not even being among the available values for 4/11/13)

Comment: Sorry I copied data incorrectly.  That should have been 180.  Although Release Qty and Qty Shipped will not necessarily be the same values.

Comment: Can you post table structure and sample data (sqlfiddle.com would be nice)?  A little difficult understanding your question.  BTW -- since you're using the jhead table in your WHERE clause, no need for a couple of those LEFT JOINs.

Comment: I reworked my SELECT statement and tried to show some sample data.

Comment: Can you show the relevant columns and the values for the sample data for each of the three tables you're selecting from.  If the OR table only contains a release data and a quantity, how can you possibly tell that the information is the slightest bit relevant to `PD.oqjob` of 17760.  And if you had `oqjob` of 17770 to process too, how would the rows in OR distinguish between the two `oqjob` values?  I think your table schema is badly misdesigned — given the limited information we have available to us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an Any to Any join, which is indicative of your query not joining on properly unique keys.

To be honest, there isn't enough information to make sense of why that's happening, but given that the quantities and dates (dbo.opakd and dbo.jhead) match, the keying problem would seem to be with the join to the dbo.orels table:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.orels [or]
    ON pd.oqord = [or].orord AND pd.oqline = [or].orline
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PD.oqjob AS Job
 , [OR].ordate AS [Release Date]
 , [OR].orrqty AS [Release Qty]
 , PH.opsdte AS [Ship Date]
 , PD.oqaqty AS [Ship Qty]
FROM
  dbo.opakh PH
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.opakd PD
    ON PH.oppack = PD.oqpack
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.orels [OR]
    ON PD.oqord = [OR].orord AND PD.oqolin = [OR].orline
WHERE
  PD.oqjob = '17760'
  AND [OR].orrqty = PD.oqaqty
  ORDER BY [Release Date], [Ship Date]
```

Looks like adding where orrqty and oqaqty to where would give you the results desired...

Answer (score 0):

A little hard to completely be sure we understand what you're after, here is my best attempt at trying.

The key is to introduce a `ROW_NUMBER()` to maintain your sorting, and to get the `DISTINCT` records from `OR` table.  Also you'll need to separate your results and use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to combine them back -- I used 2 common table expressions to separate.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT PD.oqjob AS Job
   , PH.opsdte AS [Ship Date]
   , PD.oqaqty AS [Ship Qty]
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PD.oqjob ORDER BY PH.opsdte) rn
  FROM
    dbo.opakh PH
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.opakd PD
      ON PH.oppack = PD.oqpack
  ), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Release Date]) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PD.oqjob AS Job
     , [OR].ordate AS [Release Date]
     , [OR].orrqty AS [Release Qty]
    FROM
      dbo.opakh PH
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.opakd PD
        ON PH.oppack = PD.oqpack
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.orels [OR]
        ON PD.oqord = [OR].orord AND PD.oqolin = [OR].orline
    ) T
  ) 
SELECT CTE.Job, [Release Date], [Release Qty], [Ship Date], [Ship Qty]
FROM CTE 
  FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.Job = CTE2.Job AND CTE.rn = CTE2.rn
WHERE CTE.Job = 17760 OR CTE2.Job = 17760
ORDER BY COALESCE(CTE.rn,1000000), COALESCE(CTE2.rn,1000000)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33a19/9)

I added an extra record in your `OR` table to show the `NULL` return as well.  Also notice in the `ORDER BY`, I used `COALESCE` around each rn.  Just make sure whatever number in your `COALESCE` couldn't possibly be returned.